# How to refactor this constructor?

Tags: typescript

I made a TypeScript class AccessToken, which is to convert the plain object to a class:

```
export class AccessToken implements IAccessToken {
  public readonly access_token: string
  public readonly created_at: number
  public readonly expires_in: number
  public readonly refresh_token: string
  public readonly scope: string
  public readonly token_type: string | undefined
  public readonly consented_on: number | undefined
  public readonly refresh_token_expires_in: number | undefined

  constructor(data: IAccessToken) {
    this.access_token = data.access_token
    this.created_at = data.created_at
    this.expires_in = data.expires_in
    this.refresh_token = data.refresh_token
    this.scope = data.scope
    this.token_type = data.token_type
    this.consented_on = data.consented_on
    this.refresh_token_expires_in = data.refresh_token_expires_in

    R.difference(R.keys(data), ['access_token', 'created_at', 'expires_in', 'refresh_token', 'scope', 'token_type', 'consendted_on', 'refresh_token_expires_in']).forEach(element => {
      this[element] = data[element]
    });
  }

  public isValid() {...}

  ...
}
```

The code is ugly. But if I deleted the `this.xxx = data.xxx`, then the compiler will say `Property xxx has no initializer and it not definitely assigned in the constructor`.

[image]

But write them line by line is stupid.

Can anyone show a better constructor? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Don't create unnecessary abstraction on data structure.**

I suggest you drop this class :)

You're trying to add another abstraction (complexity) on data structure, using the wrapper class.

There is no benefits with your approach. At the end you will have the class which breaks **Single Responsibility Principle**.  `IAccessToken` is just a data structure.

All you need are just algorithms.

```
export interface IAccessToken {

}

export class AccessTokenValidator {
    isValid(token: IAccessToken): boolean {
        // ...
    }
}

export function validateAccessToken(token: IAccessToken): boolean {
       // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this (using `Object.assign` method):

```
export class AccessToken implements IAccessToken {
      public readonly access_token!: string
      public readonly created_at!: number
      public readonly expires_in!: number
      public readonly refresh_token!: string
      public readonly scope!: string
      public readonly token_type: string | undefined
      public readonly consented_on: number | undefined
      public readonly refresh_token_expires_in: number | undefined

      constructor(data: IAccessToken) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
      }

  public isValid() {...}

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying , but your solution is the exact problem which I am trying to work around it. The compiler will say `Property xxx has no initializer and it not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

Comment: You can add `!` sign `public readonly access_token!: string` or disable `strictPropertyInitialization` lint rule...Just like work around

Comment: Thank you. Will change my vote when the StackOverflow allows me to.